# Why should we have to build the project first before executing the SonarQube code analysis in Azure DevOps?

Tags: sonarqube

I am just curious to know why should we have to build (MSBuild) the project first before executing the SonarQube code analysis in Azure DevOps?
If we don't build the project first, it is throwing an error like

```
Post-processing started.
##[error]11:17:23.752  The SonarScanner for MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
Possible causes:
  1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end ste
```

Is this mandatory to integrate the SQ? Is there a way to bypass this, I mean I just wanted to run the Code Analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the points made by [David M. Karr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10508/david-m-karr), in the specific case of the C# and VB.NET the Sonar analysis rules are implemented as [Roslyn](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/) analyzers, which means they are executed by the compiler as part of the build. No build, no analysis.

SonarCloud has a feature called [AutoScan](https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/analysis/automatic-analysis/) which provides build-free analysis for some languages, but not currently for C#.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube does more than just static analysis of your source code.  It needs some build artifacts to do a complete analysis.

For instance, SonarQube cannot report on unit test coverage without the data file that is produced by running the unit tests.  Obviously, you can't run the unit tests without compiling your code.

Some language analysis tools also require the compiled files, in addition to, or in place of, the source code files.